# jqGrid Autocomplete is displaying behind the add / edit form

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete in jqGrid, but the autocomplete list is displayed behind the add / edit form.  I am using the latest jQuery UI and jqGrid. Here is the code snippet:

```js
colModel : [
  {
    name: "birthPlaceId",
    index: "birthPlaceId",
    editable: true,
    edittype: "text",
    hidden: true
  }, {
    name: "birthPlaceName",
    index: "birthPlaceName",
    editable: true,
    editoptions: {
      size: 75,
      dataInit: function (e) {
        $(e).autocomplete({
          source: "${ajaxPlacesUrl}",
          minLength: 1,
          focus: function (event, ui) {
            $(e).val(ui.item.label);
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {
            $(e).val(ui.item.label);
            $("input#birthPlaceId").val(ui.item.value);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    editrules: {
      edithidden: true,
      required: false
    },
    edittype: "text",
    hidden: true,
    width: 75
  }
]
```

Here is the JSON data getting from the server for **"W"**:

```js
[{"value":30,"label":"Washington, DC, USA"},
 {"value":31,"label":"Windsor, Ontario, Canada"},
 {"value":111,"label":"Wylie, Texas, USA"}]
```

I searched and couldn't find a fix for this. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with displaying of jQuery UI Autocomplete menu behind the Add/Edit form can be solved typically in one from two ways. The first way will be the usage of [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option of jQuery UI Autocomplete. The option van change place of Autocomplete menu on the page. Another way will be to change `z-index` of Add/Edit form. You can use [zIndex](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property to reduce the default 950 value to some less value. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371227/315935) for the code example.

Comment: Oleg, thanks for your fast response. I added {zIndex:1234} to add and edit forms, autocomplete is still displaying behind the add / edit forms.  I also tried appendTo option of Autocomplete and it did not bring the autocomplete at all.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @mj8591: You should **reduce** the value of `z-index`. The default value is `950`. If you increase it to `1234` the Add/Edit form will stay over the autocomplete menu.

Comment: I changed {zIndex:99} and added <style type="text/css">
  .ui-front {
    z-index: 1000;
  }
</style>
 it works fine now.  Thanks for your help.