# JqGrid Navigator forms are displayed under modal window

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid (with navigator buttons like add, edit and delete ) on a modal window. When I click on add, the form is getting displayed under the current modal window. How can I bring the form to front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problems can be solved by setting `z-index` CSS property on the div with the form. For example you can use [zIndex](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property of add/edit options of `navGrid`. See [the anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371227/315935) for an code example.